# In the Aladdin remake, wouldn’t Jasmine be Sultana?

Tags: aladdin-2019

At the end of the film,

> Jasmine gets named “Sultan,” but “Sultana” is the female equivalent  of “Sultan.”

Comment: Or possibly a raisin

Comment: The Ottomans used "sultan" both for men and women, although the women were never the ruler (at least formally). So there's precedent for using "sultan" for both men and women

Comment: @Gallifreyan So you're saying they went with Turkish as opposed to Arabic? Good idea, didn't think of that.

Comment: Sultana is a very specific Turkish grape race. They are not produced only to be raisins and they are way more delicious than other grapes according to my experience.

Comment: I think it may be worth checking if there is a subbed or dubbed version in Arabic, and whether she is still "Sultan" in it. My own guess is no. The English version is, well, English, and does not need to adhere to the semantic genders of Arabic. The word "sultan" is far more familiar to English speakers than "sultana," and I don't think it creates any confusion as to whether Jasmine is really female.

Comment: Maybe it's because he was raisin' her to be royalty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to wikipedia the title [Sultana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultana_(title)) refers to both a ruling female monarch and to the wife of a ruling male monarch, i.e. ruling Sultana as well as Sultan's consort wife.

That said, Jasmine being in the first category, the title most certainly applies to her.

I don't know why they went with "Sultan" in the movie, perhaps they thought it sounded more gender neutral or maybe they just didn't give it much thought.

My own theory stems from one comment made by Jaffar, something along the lines that Agrabbah never had a female ruler. It made me remember [a similar story from Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jadwiga_of_Poland). Apparently the old king had only one child, a daughter, and the lack of male heirs threatened a succession crisis. It was the best for everyone that she inherits the title, except that the law explicitly stated that "a Queen may not rule the country". So, they crowned her a King - there wasn't a single law stating that the King in question has to be male. So, if we really want to rationalize this detail in-universe, something like this is what I'd go with.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is clearly "no", because if her official title was "Sultana", they'd call her that instead of "Sultan". The long answer is that, while "sultana" is indeed the female equivalent of "sultan", **not every Arabic nation used it to refer to female rulers.** [The same Wikipedia article Goran linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultana_(title)) notes that "In the west, the title of sultana is also used to refer to many female Muslim monarchs who don't hold this title officially."

Razia al-Din, the first known woman to have ruled an Islamic nation, is popularly known in the West as "Razia Sultana" ([it's what her Wikipedia page is called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razia_Sultana)), but actually refused to be addressed as that and insisted on being called "Sultan" - biographies of her made in her homeland (Delhi, India) correctly refer to her as "Razia Sultan". The second, Shajar al-Durr, was referred to as "sultan" in coinage.

We can therefore assume that Agrabah is one of those nations where female rulers are still referred to as "Sultan" instead of Sultana.

Comment: Hey, why can’t Both these answers be ticked? I like both of them!

Answer (score 2):

The actress who plays Jasmine, Naomi Scott and the actor who plays the Genie, Will Smith both use both terms *interchangeably* when describing her character.

> *“I love the fact that the power is then in in her hands, and that **she becomes the Sultana,”*** Naomi Scott revealed to Yahoo, *“She's like, ‘Well, I'm a boss lady, so I’ll just change the law!’ And she's actively pushing forward her own narrative. I just love that.”*
>
> <sub><sup>['Aladdin': Naomi Scott explains why Princess Jasmine's story has been updated for 2019](https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/aladdin-naomi-scott-explains-why-princess-jasmines-story-has-been-updated-for-2019-160452309.html)</sup></sub>

and

> The actor who plays the blue genius of Aladdin, Will Smith, claimed
> today in London the right of women to govern criticizing that ***“it is
> ridiculous that a woman can not be a sultana”***, in reference to one of
> the obstacles that Princess Jasmine must face in the film.
>
> <sub><sup>[“It’s Ridiculous That A Woman Can Not Be A Sultana,” Says Will Smith
> About Aladdin’s Plot](https://matzavreview.com/2019/05/11/its-ridiculous-that-a-woman-can-not-be-a-sultana-says-will-smith-about-aladdins-plot/)</sup></sub>

---

I would assume that the decision was made to make her a Sultan rather than a Sultana *in the film* simply because it's not a word that most people (especially an American audience) would know other than in the context of dried fruit.

Comment: Can confirm: I opened this question entirely confused on why someone was asking if Jasmine would be dried fruit.